JSON code for hover over a SharePoint List column A and shows the data of column B as a card, Is that possible?
I am looking for JSON-code that when a user hovers over a SharePoint List column A and shows the data of column B as a card. And the column B is hidden, Is that possible?
Gr. P

What is the column/data type of Column B in your list?

Showing hover over is possible with using SharePoint JSON formatting. However, there might be few limitations of JSON formatting (based on your requirements). Hence, need more information. 1. What is the column/data type of Column B in your list? 2. Is the column B type supports filtering/sorting, etc. in SharePoint?

There are lots of samples for JSON formatting in Github. Try the custom hover card for your purpose and adjust to your list specifics.
The screenshot below shows a custom card on hover of an item. The hover card shows additional details about an item's status, which come from other columns.
https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/custom-hover-card


If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.
